# Existence of Triply periodic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

I know elliptic functions are examples of Doubly periodic function. Does triply periodic function exist? If yes, is there any method to construct this type of function.
Can we extend this to n -periodic functions?

It is just my approach. I don't know whether it is right or not.
Please explain.

Comment: You're talking about functions  $f:\mathbf{C}\to\mathbf{C},$ is that right?

Comment: Of  course , I am talking about functions on complex plane.

Comment: Here's a short blog post about it:  https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2015/09/27/doubly-and-triply-periodic-functions/

Comment: I have cleared my concept.Thanks